# Spreading arrays into arguments, doesn't seem to work for Observable.pipe(...myOperatorsArray)

Tags: typescript, rxjs6

we create

> ob.pipe(map(),map(),map())

all the time, well it should be possible to have

> let myMaps = [map(),map(),map()]

then later call

> ob.pipe(myMaps)

somehow.

This is simplified version of my use case in typescript

```
declare type InterceptorFunc = (m: Message) => Observable < Message >

  export function interceptorMap(interceptorFunc: InterceptorFunc):
  (source: Observable < Message > ) => Observable < Message > {
    console.log("interceptorMap") //[1]never see this in the console
    return (source: Observable < Message > ) => source.pipe(flatMap(e => {
      console.log("interceptorMap: msg: ", e) //[2]nor this
      return interceptorFunc(e);
    }));
  }

addInterceptor(interceptor: Function /*InterceptorFunc*/ ) {
  this.interceptorFuncArray.push( < InterceptorFunc > interceptor)
}

/**
 * Apply interceptors
 */
//message intercept

( < any > this.preReplayEventsSubject.asObservable()).pipe(
    ...(this.interceptorFuncArray.map(f => interceptorMap(f))),
    map((m: Message) => {
      console.log("Message after apply interceptors: ", m) //[3]see this in the console and the message appears like it has never flowed through any interceptor Funcs in the array
      return m;
    }))
  .subscribe((m: Message) => {//[4]
    this.replayEventsSubject.next(m);
  });
```

So in comment [1] and [2] the console.log statements inside the custom operator, are never executed. In comment [3] the Message objects which are changed in the operators, are unchanged, but the fact that this console.log statement executes, would suggest the event has to pass through the spread array, to get there.

I tried defining a InterceptorFunc which returns null and then pipped that into a filter(e => !!) the comment [3] and [4] code still runs where the filter with null event should stop the flow for that Message object completely.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the important part is that you can [give customized a function](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.2.0/src/internal/Observable.ts#L282) to `pipe`operator :

```
obs.pipe(
 (observable) => doSomething(observable, ...),
 otherOperators(callbackFunction)
)
```

Here is a minimalist sample of code that answers that should work for you :

```js
// import rxjs
const {of} = rxjs;
const {map} = rxjs.operators;


/*
  apply a chain of `map` operations
*/
function mapAll(obs, operations) {
  return obs.pipe(
    map(v => {
      return operations.reduce((accVal, currentOp) => {
        return currentOp(accVal)
      }, v)
    })
  )
}


let result = [];
let observable = of(result);

// The idea here is to verify that each operation pushes into result
let op1 = (r) => {r.push(1); return r};
let op2 = (r) => {r.push(2); return r};
let op3 = (r) => {r.push(3); return r};

let operations = [op1, op2, op3];

observable.pipe(
  (obs) => mapAll(obs, operations)
)
  .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.2.1/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

`let` operator from `RxJs < 5.5`, has been replaced with `pipe`, they have the same signature. I guess you could find more [examples](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/let.html) with `let̀ on how to write customized operators.

Comment: const op = Rx.operators;//you are importing all operators in Rx.operators? Why?

Comment: @justify I imported `rxjs` javascript library. `op` is defined on line 2 as the module containing all rxjs operator. These are technicalities I think, I could import operators instead of using `op.operator`. You're right, it may be clearer. I'll edit my post.

Comment: I never got it to work, in a reasonable time frame with my use case, and implemented the logic in another way, but if you have tried it and your example does work. I'll accept the answer, maybe it will help someone down the line